# Restricting binary relations by composing with an "inclusion binary relation"

Tags: reference-request, functions, notation, relations, function-and-relation-composition

If $X' \subseteq X$ then we may define an [inclusion map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map) $\iota : X' \to X$ where $\iota(x) = x$. One use of $\iota$ is that we can express the restriction of some $f : X \to Y$ to $X'$ as $f|_{X'} = f \circ \iota$.

This can be useful when representing function restrictions in commutative diagrams. But how about restricting binary relations in commutative diagrams?

The restriction of some binary relation $R \subseteq X \times X$ to $X'$ can be rather neatly expressed as $R \cap (X')^2$, but I would like to express it as the composite relation $R \circ I$, where $I = \{(x, x)\ |\ x \in X'\}$.

So my question is, does $I$ have a standard name or notation? Maybe something like $1_{X'}$...

Comment: You need to *pre-*compose with the inclusion to build a restriction map.  I'll edit the post to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Left- and right- composition makes my head spin

Comment: (I guess that I was being presumptuous to assume that your functions are applied on the left.  Mine *usually* are.)

Comment: Why not just $\iota \times \iota$ for the inclusion $X' \times X' \hookrightarrow X \times X$?

Comment: @SammyBlack I can't see how the restriction can be expressed using $\iota \times \iota$.